# Updating master layer with data imported from GPS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import, vector-layer

All the data I import comes in from GPX files in dribs and drabs.  I load the file into a new layer using GPSTool or "Add Vector Layer" but neither of these give me any control over the fields created in the new layer.  This makes merging data into the master table difficult.

Ideally I want to be able specify what features get imported and what they are named in the new layer and also be able to populate fields like source, etc. with static data or alternately have a tool that takes the raw imported layer and adds the contents to a master layer while mapping feature names and adding static values.

It seems to me that this must be a common workflow in the GIS world and I want to make sure that I am not missing something before start coding something -- I am thinking of a more sophisticated version of the Merge Layer plugin from Michael Minn.